# How To Repurpose an Old Tablet?

Tags: android, file-management, tablet

I have an old *Android Galaxy* Tablet that is reaching the end of its useful life span. I was wondering if there is a way to convert it into more of a **file access/storage device**.

I want something I can basically use as a **Flash Drive/Thumb Drive** with a touch screen that can also access the host device storage. I was looking into maybe changing the *OS* over to straight *Linux*, but wanted to know if it would be easier to keep it on *Android* for its new life.

Is this possible?

What is the best way to repurposing my tablet? What OS should I use? How would I modify it for maximum space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you ONLY want to use your Device as ThumbDrive then do the following:

- Install TWRP-Recovery on your device
- Reboot into Recovery and wipe everything (save stuff you need first)

Thats it. AS long as you keep your Device in Recovery you are able to transfer files like with any other Thumb Drive. As you wiped the File-System there is no Operating System on there anymore.

If you want to use your Device as FTP-Server or NFS, you could just Factory Reset to Stock and then install the following app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate&hl=en

I would stay with Android as this offers Power Saving etc.